# insert combine (value and select)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are ways of inserting data into table:

```
insert into MyTable (ColA, ColB, ColC) values ('A', 'B', 'C')

insert into MyTable (ColA, ColB, ColC) select  colAA, colBB, colCC from MyTable2
```

Is there way to use `insert into MyTable (ColA, ColB, ColC) select  colAA, colBB, colCC from MyTable2` but instead of inserting for example colAA value into colA I woulkd like to insert there always 1.

THanks for help

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just add a constant into the `SELECT` list

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
            (ColA,
             ColB,
             ColC)
SELECT 1,
       colBB,
       colCC
FROM   MyTable2
```