# SQL database insert with select

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I understand that there is a way to insert a constant from select statement which i found the source from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989583/insert-combine-value-and-select) such as:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(ColA,ColB,ColC)
SELECT 1,colBB,colCC FROM MyTable2
```

But is it possible to add an user input values (using php) instead of a constant value as well? If possible provide with example. Thanks in advance.

UPDATED:
I tried to create a simple web page however there are some syntax error that i have no idea to solve it:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\result.php on line 10

Below are my codes:

```
<?php
//start a session

    require("config.inc.php");
    $username = $_SESSION["username"];
    if(!empty($_POST)){
    //check if user choose non-required drop down list
        if(empty($_POST['subcategory'])){
            if(empty($_POST['yearofstudy'])) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO comments ( username, title, message, tousername ) 
                          SELECT :username, :title, :message, username 
                          FROM utarstudents WHERE faculty = :faculty";
                          $query_params = array(
                            ':faculty' => $_POST['category'],
                            ':username' =>$username,
                            ':title' =>$_POST['title'],
                            'message' =>$_POST['message']

                            );
            }
            else {
                $query = "INSERT INTO comments ( username, title, message, tousername ) 
                          SELECT :username, :title, :message, username 
                          FROM utarstudents WHERE faculty = :faculty AND year_of_study = :yearofstudy";
                          $query_params = array(
                            ':faculty' => $_POST['category'],
                            'yearofstudy' => $_POST['yearofstudy'],
                            ':username' =>$username,
                            ':title' =>$_POST['title'],
                            'message' =>$_POST['message']
                            );
            }
        }
        else {
            if(empty($_POST['yearofstudy'])) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO comments ( username, title, message, tousername ) 
                           SELECT :username, :title, :message, username 
                          FROM utarstudents WHERE faculty = :faculty AND course = :course";
                          $query_params = array(
                            ':faculty' => $_POST['category'],
                            ':course' => $_POST['subcategory'],
                            ':username' =>$username,
                            ':title' =>$_POST['title'],
                            'message' =>$_POST['message']
                            );
            }
            else {
                $query = "INSERT INTO comments ( username, title, message, tousername ) 
                           SELECT :username, :title, :message, username 
                          FROM utarstudents WHERE faculty = :faculty AND year_of_study = :yearofstudy AND course = :course";
                          $query_params = array(
                            ':faculty' => $_POST['category'],
                            'yearofstudy' => $_POST['yearofstudy'],
                            ':course' => $_POST['subcetagory'],
                            ':username' =>$username,
                            ':title' =>$_POST['title'],
                            'message' =>$_POST['message']
                            );

            }

        }

         try {
            $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a HTML form to pass values into PHP to then place into your database.

Comment: yes, correct. I am doing a simple sending message to group of people based of some criteria. I created message table that contains fromPerson and toPerson columns and other necessary columns such as message and title as well. I wanted to add fromPerson though user login session username into message table, at the same time i want to select multiple toPerson username from another table and insert it into message table.

Comment: Then yes create a form on one page and do something along these lines 
<form action="test.php" method="GET"> then create a test.php page with all the php code that grabs the values from the form and then inserts them into your database.  A quick Google search for HTML forms should do it for you.

Comment: so after retrieving the user inputs i can straight away INSERT INTO Message VALUES(fromuser_id, message, title) SELECT userinput, fromuser, message_content, title (all these 3 are inputs), user_id (this user_id from another table) FROM another_table WHERE .....goes on....

Comment: You can either assigned the form values to variables and then place them in your Insert statement or place the values right into them.  If you toy with it and post the code here and comment back I can take a look at it for you.

Comment: Sure I will post the code later as now I have to rest its almost morning here

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and supports parameterized queries that avoid having to inject data directly. A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: thanks for the remainder tadman, i updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an edited code snippet of mine that accomplishes what you are trying to.  So in my form file I have something like this for contributing to a project:

```
<form name="contribute" method="post" action="contribute-dbquery.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    First Name:
    <input name="nameValue" type="text" size="40" maxlength="12" required/>

    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

So what it says is when Add is goto Tcontribute-dbquery.php with the value of nameValue.  Then in my contribute-dbquery.php I assign nameValue from the form to $name and then assign inset it into my database.  I assigned it to a variable because I used it on that page as well.  You can inset it right into the database if you want.

```
$name = $_POST['nameValue'];
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO mastertable (name) VALUES (' " . $name . " ')";
```

If this helps mark it as answered.  Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: "You can inset it right into the database if you want." Not without escaping you can't.